# Linking to a plugin setting page?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel

I'm trying to add a "convenience" link from within a plugin to it's general settings page. In the [General Settings](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cpTrigger) custom cpTriggers and baseCpUrl can be set to custom values and I'm wondering if there is a easy Craft variable to retrieve a link to the site's correct settings page. It would create something like this in a template.

```
http://mysite.com/customadminword/settings/plugins/mypluginname
```

Any thoughts? I could write some logic in the plugin to dig it out but it seems like I might be overlooking something obvious. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a public `getSettingsUrl()` function to your main plugin file that returns a URL string.

> A full URL is not required -- you can simply return "pluginname/settings".
>
> If this is left blank, a simple settings page will be provided, filled with whatever getSettingsHtml() returns.

You can then get the URL from elsewhere in Craft using the `PluginsService`.

```
craft()->plugins->getPlugin('pluginname')->getSettingsUrl();
```

or `PluginsVariable`:

```
{{ craft.plugins.getPlugin('pluginname').getSettingsUrl }}
```